# Short Sci-Fi Story of suddenly appearing teleporters

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago I read a Short Sci-Fi story on the web about certain people suddenly being able to teleport.

The main character has had multiple accidents where it was as if he was at the center of a small explosion.
It turns out that he has the ability to teleport. He can "pull" to teleport to a place, and push to make a localized "explosion".

He goes to a rich guy who helps him fund an institute to gather other teleporters (if they exist) and study their powers.
They get a lot of submissions, almost all of which the main character dismisses because they are unlike his experiences, except for one submission of a woman. In her video she starts by relaxing for 10 minutes, only to suddenly teleport (which coupled with the resulting video footage) tells them that she's a real teleporter.

It turns out that a lot of people have the talent. They can't be forced to fight (because they need a certain state of mind to teleport) but can be used as couriers and to transport people (ignoring borders, which causes INTERPOL to make a new police force just for them.

Another important character is a nepalese monk that is one of the strongest of the teleporters, and who accidentally destroyed his whole monastery and killed everyone there by accidentally "Pushing".

The story then goes over the next few years and ends with the monk and some compatriots stealing a Gas Giant Moon (IIRC Io) and using it to fly out of the solar system.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "years ago?"  3 years?  15?

Comment: 5-7 years ago IIRC

Comment: Remember any names ?

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi
Sadly not. The only part I can tell you is that the main character, the rich guy and the monk are male and that the first other teleporter we see is female

Comment: Sounds a lot like one of the instances of The Tomorrow People. But not enough so I'd post it as an answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_People possibly a rip-off, Tomorrow People cannot kill in any of the versions I've seen.